# How Can I Get a string of My locale's Whitespaces?

Tags: c++, string, locale, whitespace, c-strings

Given the string: `const auto foo = "lorem\tipsum"s`

I can find an iterator to the whitespace by doing: `find(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), [](const auto& i) { return isspace(i); })`

But I want the *position*. I have two options for this:

1. Use [`distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance): `distance(cbegin(foo), find(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), [](const auto& i) { return isspace(i); }))`
2. Look up [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) and construct a hardcoded string of it's contents: `foo.find_first_of(" \f\n\r\t\v")`

Clearly **2** is simpler, and it will return `string::npos` which I have to test **1** for, but I'd like to request my locale provide me with a string of all whitespaces, rather than harcoding the string. Is there a function I could use to obtain this string, or a way to cook it up?

Comment: *Clearly* option 2 is simpler? Huh. I find `distance` just fine, although the the simple `it - cbegin(foo)` is not that bad either.

Comment: @Voo *Clearly*. I've edited to add the fact that when working with positions `distance` is annoying, because I've also got to check if it's greater than `foo.size()` so I can set it to `string::npos` if necessary.

Comment: Option 3: Write your own function ("first_space" or something like that) that uses the `distance` method and use that in your code.

Comment: @molbdnilo I imagine **3** would just use **1** with a ternary to decide whether to use `string::npos` or the calculated length? If you intended something else let me know... cause just thinking about that idea makes me more committed to **2**.

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, it would (the "ternary" is completely irrelevant, though). What's the problem with that? It's reliable and efficient. (I realise that suggesting that a programmer should just go ahead and implement functions they find useful *all on their own* is slightly old-fashioned these days.) Method 2 would require you to retrieve that string every time the locale could have changed (i.e. pretty much every time you do it).

Comment: @Jonathan So to avoid writing a simple one-line helper function, you want to write a much less simple, much longer function that requires some static memory allocation? (And that ignores possible issues with the fact that locales are thread local and can change any time, which to be fair can be ignored in most programs). That just doesn't seem like much of a win to me.

Comment: @Voo On the contrary, what I'd like to do is define the `locale` I'm working with and compile a cstring of whitespace characters as `constexpr` then use that here. Given of course that I know the `locale` that I'll be working in. Now, barring that I would be willing to write a function that uses iterators...

Answer (score 1):

This is a semi naive approach but we can have a function that checks [`isspace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace) against all possible values that `char` can hold with a supplied locale and returns a string that holds only the values that return `true`.  You can than use that string with option 2.

This is an O(N) operation with  `N == std::numeric_limits<char>::max() - std::numeric_limits<char>::min()` but if you do not change the locale then you only need to run this once and capture the string.

```
std::string whitespace_string(const std::locale& loc)
{
    std::string whitespace;
    for (char ch = std::numeric_limits<char>::min(); ch < std::numeric_limits<char>::max(); ch++)
        if (std::isspace(ch, loc))
            whitespace += ch;
    // to avoid infinte loop check char max outside the for loop.
    if (std::isspace(std::numeric_limits<char>::max(), std::locale(loc)))
        whitespace += std::numeric_limits<char>::max();
    return whitespace;
}
```

And using it with

```
std::string whitespace = whitespace_string(std::locale(""));
```

Now gives you a string with all the white space characters in the current locale.  You can substitute `std::locale("")` with a different locale like `std::locale("C")` if you do not want to use the current locale.

Comment: Could we make this `constexpr`? I'm not sure if I can get `cout`'s `locale` at compile time?

Comment: @JonathanMee I do not think this can be made `constexpr` as `std::string` relies on run time allocation.  I haven't had much experience with them though.

Comment: Narrow characters are so last millennium. And you are using them in an unknown locale...

Comment: @n.m.It is fairly simple to convert this to use `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` but since the OP is using a `std::string` I gave him code that also uses a `std::string`.